# Authlogic accessing user id in session object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I was wondering if anyone knows how I can access the user ID from the session object in Rails using the Authlogic gem  ?

I have a sweeper that runs to expire a cache fragment specific to a user:

```
 def expire_cache_for(record)
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.debug "team: #{record.team_id}"
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.debug("User: #{session}")

    # Expire a fragment
    expire_fragment(:controller => 'groups',  :action => "team_#{record.team_id}_user_#{current_user.id}")
  end
```

How can I access the user ID from my sweeper to expire the fragment using Authlogic ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using your UserSession model (or whatever model you've added that derives from Authlogic::Session::Base):

```
current_user = UserSession.find
id = current_user && current_user.record.id
```

Comment: Doesn't UserSession.find return a UserSession object and not a User object? the current user would be UserSession.find.user

Comment: John Pignata is correct.   The session stores the acts_as_authentic model in a variable record, which is the same regardless of the name of the acts_as_authentic model.